# Example of a ring whose minimals are annihilators of idempotents?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, local-rings, ac.commutative-algebra

I'm looking for examples<sup>†</sup>  of rings with the property that for each 
$P={\rm Ann}_R(a)\in{\rm Min}(R)$ then $a\in R$ is idempotent (ie $a^2=a$)

<sub><sub>† other than domains!</sub></sub>

Comment: One is $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x(x-1))$.

Comment: Given $P$, it's quite unclear whether you're asking that $a$ be idempotent for *every* $a$ such that $P=Ann(a)$ or that $a$ be idempotent for *some* $a$ such that $P=Ann(a)$.  If the latter, take the direct sum of two domains.

Comment: @Steven Landsburg:The latter case is what I mean:$P=Ann_R(a)$ for some idempotent $a$. 